# Both actions cannot be performed simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a progress bar by using data-atribute, but in Jquery both actions cannot be performed simultaneously.

```html
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progressvalue" data-percent="50"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.progressbar {
    background: #9696A0;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.progressvalue {
    background: #4650C8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```js
$('.progressvalue').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('width', $this.data('percent') + '%');
    $this.parent().text('tournament progress: ' + $this.data('percent') + '%');
});
```

The result is:

[image]

But it should be:

[image]

Comment: What is problem? See https://jsfiddle.net/usyL2vcw/

Comment: I saw that I missed "$" before the second this of Jquery, but the problem is that only text appear... I need the text and the background of the progressvalue to appear.

Comment: Try inspecting the DOM after setting the text, looks like the coloured element is being removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues. Here's a working solution. https://jsfiddle.net/usyL2vcw/1/

Your first issue is that you are using `this` instead of `$this`.
Your second issue is that you can't change the `text` of a `div` that has children (You can but it replaces the children). Use a sibling span instead.

```
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progressvalue" data-percent="50"></div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

---

```
$('.progressvalue').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('width', $this.data('percent') + '%');
    $this.siblings().text('tournament progress: ' + $this.data('percent') + '%');
});
```